# Busqueda tiempo real en DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access-2010

Estoy usando el siguiente código pero cuando lo ejecuto y empiezo a escribir en el `TextBox` me marca el error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida
>   como instancia de un objeto.'

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (per_fisDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format
            ("nombre LIKE '%{0}%' OR rfc LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Podrías por favor agregar el error que te da.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Comment: Un caso que tuve esque los datos del DataGridView los cargaba con Rows.Add, por lo que era imposible hacer la referencia con Datatable, lo que quiero decir con eso esque veas si los datos que cargas en  per_fisDataGridView vienen de un datatable...

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que hagas un debuggeo y te asegures de 2 cosas:

1. La propiedad `DataSource` del `DataGridView` no es `null` (o que sea
   un tipo de dato diferente al tipo que estás casteando `DataTable`)
2. La propiedad `DefaultView` no es `null`

Igualmente puedes facilitarnos el Stack trace del Inner Exception para saber más detalles.
Saludos.